# Get position of Item in GridView from SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView, with a `DataTemplate` which is similar to the default one included in the W8.1 Grid App Template. It's populated (through binding) from a CollectionViewSource.

The `GridView`'s `SelectionMode` is `Single` and I have subscribed to the `GridView`'s `SelectionChanged` event. Inside this event, I can get the object that is currently selected by using this code -

```
private void itemGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ItemCanvas icDelete = ((GridView)sender).SelectedItem as ItemCanvas;
  string sName = icDelete.Name;
}
```

How can I access the `DataTemplate` of this item, i.e. how can I access the visual location of this item so I can show a Popup where this item is located in the GridView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it by using a Flyout, my code:

**My XAML:**

```
   ...data template..
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout >
                                        <Flyout>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="flag_" >
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="hide_" >

                                                <TextBlock Width="200" x:Name="details" Text="{Binding title}"  />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Flyout>
                                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

**My C#:**

```
   private void Border_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Border brdr = sender as Border;
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(brdr);

        }
```

And it's working great!

Comment: That does work great, thank you !